# How to change Windows 8 Explorer theme to get it look like...?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

[image]

I've seen this posted by "paranoid"... Could someone call him so he get here?

Sorry for my english

Comment: This question is really hard to understand. You want us to call some one? Please [click here to edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/756959/edit) and make it clear what your question is, or it will likely be closed (put on hold)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This the Windows 8 Release Preview Theme. You can use the Theme directly from the Release Preview or [download it from here](http://winaero.com/blog/windows-8-release-preview-theme-for-windows-8-rtm/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell (guess), you are referring to wanting the Win8 interface to look a above in your question.  The problem I have with the question (besides the lacking content!) is that this appears to be the default layout.

To get the colour scheme correct - go to control panel > Appearance > Display > "Change the colour of your taskbar and window borders".  Again, this assumes you are running win8 and you are trying to restore this look.

If you have the "control ribbon" (copy, paste, delete) etc showing.. you can right click it and hide it.

If I am completely wrong and you are running a different OS (XP/Vista/7/Linux) which you want to skin to look like this - then google is your friend.  There are multiple good solutions out there - some of them free.. but we don't do software recommendations on superuser I'm afraid.

Hope some of this helps a little.

Comment: We can't **ask** for software recommendations... there is nothing wrong with making recommendations in answers though! :)